# What is hyperloop gem and why do we use it with react?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm trying to add react component to rails and I've been recommended to use hyperloop gem.

```
// app/assets/javascripts/application.js
...
//= hyperloop-loader
```

Now I can't understand why hyperloop gem is used in this case and what's the purpose of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyperloop's primary goal is to allow you to enjoy quickly building modern interactive web applications.

You have full access to the entire Rails ecosystem and universe of front-end JavaScript libraries like React and jQuery - all using one great language - Ruby.

Hyperloop lets you write code that is directed toward solving the user's needs in the most straightforward manner, without redundant code, unnecessary APIs, or artificial separation between client and server.

Our (isomorphic) framework consists of Components, Operations, Models, Policies, and Stores. This structure is analogous to and replaces the older MVC architecture, but with a more logical and finer grained division of labor.

[image]

I am sure you can get more information [here](http://ruby-hyperloop.io/docs/architecture/) and also sample ToDo app tutorial [here](http://ruby-hyperloop.io/tutorials/hyperlooprails/todo-tutorial/)